# highlight keywords in string in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter. I need to highlight keywords in string, normally using replace method we can achieve it but in flutter it seems difficult.

Here is the code I am trying.

```
  Widget getString() {
    List<TextSpan> lsTextSpan = [];
    String str = 'This is new year and I have new bicycle.';
    List<String> lskeywords = ['new year', 'bicycle'];
    //here need code ?????
    return RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
      children: lsTextSpan,
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change regex pattern as you wish.

`RegExp(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+')` is replacing special characters except 'a-zA-Z0-9'.

```
RichText(
  text: _getText(
    text: 'This is new year and I have new bicycle.',
    highlightedTextList: ['new', 'bicycle'],
  ),
),

TextSpan _getText({String text, List<String> highlightedTextList}) {
    return TextSpan(
      children: _highLight(
        text: text,
        highlightedTextList: highlightedTextList,
      ),
    );
  }

List<TextSpan> _highLight({String text, List<String> highlightedTextList}) {
    var splittedText = text.split(' ');
    var spans = <TextSpan>[];
    var pattern = RegExp(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+');
    for (var i = 0; i < splittedText.length; i++) {
      var index = highlightedTextList.indexWhere((element) {
        return splittedText[i].replaceAll(pattern, '') == element;
      });
      spans.add(
        TextSpan(
          text: '${splittedText[i]} ',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: index > -1 ? Colors.blueAccent : Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return spans;
  }
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this code works only for single word, replace `bicycle` with `I have` and then check.

Comment: Yes. Because we are splitting main string from whitespaces for words comparing.

You can pass the list like this : ['new', 'I', 'have']

Comment: `['new','I','have']` in that case it will highlight all the occurrences of `I` and `have` and that is not expected behavior

Comment: It works on my case thanks.